# Format numeric data table rowwise in R using tidyverse for kable output

Tags: r, dataframe, format, tidyverse, kable

I have a table of values that I want to save as a `kable()` table. Each row of the table is a variable and each column is a value of that variable (e.g., a mean, minimum, maximum, etc.). You can apply the `format()` function to columns of a data frame but applying it across rows seems very awkward. I finally achieved my goal with this code, but would be interested if there is a `tidier` way of doing it!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(kableExtra)

# test data
all <- tibble(PARAMETER=c("A","B", "C"), 
              Value1=c(0.0123, 1230, NA), 
              Value2=c(0.0234, 2340, 1.23), 
              Units=c("m", "Pa", "ha"), 
              Description=c("Length", "Pressure", "Area"))

# my formatting function
my_format <- function(x){
  y <- format(x, digits=3, scientific=FALSE, TRIM=TRUE)
  y[is.na(x)] <- ""
  y
}

# format values by row
all_formatted <- all %>%
  `row.names<-`(.$PARAMETER) %>% # set row names for transpose
  select(-PARAMETER, -Units, -Description) %>% # only numeric columns
  t() %>% # transpose
  tidy() %>% # convert to tibble (creates .rownames column)
  modify(my_format) %>% # apply format function to each column of values in place
  `row.names<-`(.$.rownames) %>% # set row names for transpose
  select(-.rownames) %>% # drop rownames column
  t() %>% # transpose
  tidy() %>% # convert to tibble (creates .rownames column)
  select(-.rownames) %>% # drop rownames
  add_column(PARAMETER=all$PARAMETER, .before=1) %>% # add back nonnumeric columns
  add_column(UNITS=all$Units, 
             DESCRIPTION=all$Description)

# print formatted table
all_formatted %>%
  kable() %>%
  kable_styling(
    bootstrap_options = c("condensed", "striped", "hover"),
    full_width=FALSE, position="left", font_size=12) %>%
  save_kable(file="temp.html", self_contained=TRUE) # very slow
```

[image]

Comment: requested at https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/357.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how attached you are to `kable`, but `flextable` is one of my favorite things and it usually renders to HTML and .doc the same way. The trick is to do it by column, not row... just specify the characteristics of the numbers you want to format differently:

```
library(flextable)
all %>% regulartable() %>% align(align="center",part="all") %>% 
    set_formatter(Value1 = function(x) 
                     ifelse(x > 1, sprintf("%.0f", x), sprintf("%.03f", x) ),
                  Value2 = function(x) 
                     ifelse(x > 1, sprintf("%.0f", x), sprintf("%.03f", x) ))
```

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I don't really mind what package. The issue is that you gets unwanted decimal places on the second row. I want to jointly format the values on each row independently.

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting question. Let me see if I can make that happen.

Comment: Thanks! As I said, I did achieve it, by transposing the data frame and then applying `format()`, but it was awkward.